# How to remove loading window from Jasper Server

Tags: jasperserver

I want to remove the loading window, that appears when report loads/refresh.
How to do this?

Can anyone tell me the file name in the jasper server installation directory that should I change at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **loading.jsp** file in the Jasper Server installation directory(***tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\jsp\templates\loading.jsp***) comment below part

```
<t:insertTemplate template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/container.jsp">
    <t:putAttribute name="containerID" value="${not empty containerID ? containerID : 'loading'}"/>
    <t:putAttribute name="containerClass">panel dialog loading overlay moveable centered_horz centered_vert ${containerClass}</t:putAttribute>
    <t:putAttribute name="containerTitle"><spring:message code='jsp.wait'/></t:putAttribute>
    <t:putAttribute name="headerClass" value="mover"/>
    <t:putAttribute name="bodyContent" >
    
    <p class="message" role="alert" aria-live="assertive"><spring:message code='jsp.loading'/></p>
    <button id="cancel" class="button action up"><span class="wrap"><spring:message code="button.cancel"/></span><span class="icon"></span></button>
    
    </t:putAttribute>   
</t:insertTemplate>
```

When you do like above example, loading window will be disappear from everywhere.

To remove loading for a specific report,

put two ***div*** tags with ***id*** attribute. then hide the div using js code.

**Below I shown the example;**

```
<div id="prabu">
    <div id="x3">
        <t:insertTemplate template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/container.jsp">
            <t:putAttribute name="containerID" value="${not empty containerID ? containerID : 'loading'}"/>
            <t:putAttribute name="containerClass">panel dialog loading overlay moveable centered_horz centered_vert ${containerClass}</t:putAttribute>
            <t:putAttribute name="containerTitle"><spring:message code='jsp.wait'/></t:putAttribute>
            <t:putAttribute name="headerClass" value="mover"/>
            <t:putAttribute name="bodyContent" >
    
                <p class="message" role="alert" aria-live="assertive"><spring:message code='jsp.loading'/></p>
                <button id="cancel" class="button action up"><span class="wrap"><spring:message code="button.cancel"/></span><span class="icon"></span></button>
    
            </t:putAttribute>   
        </t:insertTemplate> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Then add below javascript code;**

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.href; //take current tab url
    var dash = 'http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2FMy_Reports&reportUnit=%2FMy_Reports%2FDashboard_Report_Original__2_&standAlone=true';

    if(url === dash ){
        removeElement("x3");

    }

    function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
</script>
```

In my case, I use a report as my dashboard and I refresh it in every 1 minute.So I want to remove loading window for my dashboard report only.

On js code,
**url** is current url from the browser.
**dash** is the my dashboard report url.